# Query for this situation

Tags: sql, logic

I have a table like this:

```
EMP_ID   emp_name Designation  DOB        Address
--------------------------------------------------
101         X         Null     Null       NULL
101       NULL      Engineer   Null       null
101       NULL       NULL      31/07/1992 Null
101       NULL       NULL       NULL      XYLEM
```

This is basically a single row scattered information across. How to query it so we can get the single result row?

Comment: You probably have an error in the SQL that generates this result set.

Answer (score 1):

We can try taking the max of each column:

```
SELECT
    EMP_ID,
    MAX(emp_name) AS emp_name,
    MAX(Designation) AS Designation,
    MAX(DOB) AS DOB,
    MAX(Address) AS Address
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    EMP_ID;
```

However, given the unnormalized layout of your current table, I might wager that you made a data design decision incorrectly somewhere along the way.  Normally, you would not want to store your information this way.

Comment: Thanks Tim Correct its just an Scenario Not an actual Situation. Kind Regard

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    EMP_ID,
    MAX(emp_name) AS emp_name,
    MAX(Designation) AS Designation,
    MAX(DOB) AS DOB,
    MAX(Address) AS Address
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    EMP_ID;
```

OR

```
SELECT
    EMP_ID,
    MIN(emp_name) AS emp_name,
    MIN(Designation) AS Designation,
    MIN(DOB) AS DOB,
    MIN(Address) AS Address
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    EMP_ID;
```